# The function makeRDD of SparkContex?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("TestAPP")

val sc=new SparkContext(conf)

When I used sc.makeRDD(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)),Then the following tips appear.

[image].

I want to know why this happened.And How to use makeRDD correctly.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. What version of spark are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same, its working.

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark example")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()
  val seqExam = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  val employeeRDD = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(seqExam)
  employeeRDD.foreach { x => println(x) }
```

Comment: foreach shouldn't be use to print, it is usually used for side effects such as updating an accumulator or interacting with external storage systems. So this should print anything

Comment: The reason is that I was using Maven to create the project is not configured with the appropriate class library. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in other way i.e. to use `parallelize` :

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("SparkParallelizeExample")
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()
  val seqExam = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  val employeeRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(seqExam)
  employeeRDD.foreach { x => println(x) }
```

Comment: `foreach` shouldn't be use to print, it is usually used for side effects such as updating an accumulator or interacting with external storage systems. So this should print anything. And also this doesn't answer the question. The question is about type inference using makeRDD

Comment: @eliasah: Agreed ! But this will work right ! if you are using spark in standalone mode !

Comment: and by this do you mean printing or parallelizing ?

Comment: by this i meant the code ! this code will work right ? Sorry i was not able to get the right context of the question1

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. I just wanted to make thing clear for you :)

Comment: Thanks , you did it twice today ! Thanks a lot :D